# Repeat a section in the HTML page

Tags: aspose, aspose.pdf

[image]

Hi everyone!

I have this template which uses a table and I want that the section "Repeat this section depending on total records" be repeated. The scenario is that a certain person can have multiple entries (which will be placed in the "repeat this section...") and once that is created, I will convert this into a pdf page with breaks.

Is there a way to do this? The result will be something like this

[image]

Comment: Aspose.PDF for .NET API can help you to convert HTML files to PDF or adding HTML string to a PDF page with the help of HTMLFragment Class. You would need to devise rest of the algorithm based on your requirements. 
HtmlFragment title = new HtmlFragment("<fontsize=10><b><i>Table</i></b></fontsize>");
page.Paragraphs.Add(title);
Or you may directly convert whole HTML file to PDF so that the generated file may appear exactly as source file. **PS:** I work with Aspose as Developer Evangelist.

Comment: @FarhanRaza OK. I understand how it is. However, is it possible to have like two separate html templates (header and details) whereby the details duplicate and combine these two before converting it to pdf?

Comment: You may convert both HTML files to PDF individually and then concatenate pages of those two PDF documents into one as per your requirements.